# "Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count" is coming when i am using ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I want to get value by returning from SQl Procedure, but i am getting this error "Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count."
My code is:

```
public int getControlTypeIDByVal()
    {
        int retVal = 0;
        try
        {
            SqlParameter[] _param = new SqlParameter[2];
            _param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ControlName2", ControlName);
            _param[1] = new SqlParameter("@RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
            _param[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            SqlDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlDataAccess.ConnectionString, "PR_getControlTypeIDByVal", _param);
            if (!clsCommonFn.isNullOrEmpty(_param[1].ToString()))
            {
                retVal = Convert.ToInt32(_param[1]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorMsg = e.Message;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

and Sp is :-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PR_getControlTypeIDByVal
@ControlName2   NVARCHAR(200)
AS
-- EXEC PR_getControlTypeIDByVal 'Jaisalmer 2N/3D'
BEGIN
DECLARE @retVal INT
SET @retVal=0
    SELECT @retVal=ControlTypeID FROM ControlTypes
    WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(ControlName))=LTRIM(RTRIM(@ControlName2))
PRINT(@retVal)  
RETURN @retVal
END
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code of  SqlDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery() function

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `ExecuteNonQuery()`, then you can change **ParameterDirection** to `ParameterDirection.OutPut`. If this is the case, in c# you are declaring two parameters, one for input and one for output. But in SQL Server you are not declaring output parameter.

You need to define the output parameter explicitly. Can you try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PR_getControlTypeIDByVal
    @ControlName2   NVARCHAR(200)
    @retVal INT OUTPUT
    AS
    -- EXEC PR_getControlTypeIDByVal 'Jaisalmer 2N/3D'
    BEGIN

    SET @retVal=0
        SELECT @retVal=ControlTypeID FROM ControlTypes
        WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(ControlName))=LTRIM(RTRIM(@ControlName2))

    RETURN
    END
```

**UPDATE:**  If you want to use `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` you can use something like this **without changing your SP**:

```
retVal = yourSQLCommand.Parameters[@retVal].value;
```

But instead, you can return the result by not adding a return value in the first place and using something like this:

```
retVal = Convert.ToInt32(yourSQLCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: when we create parameter as parameterdirection.output, then we have to write output in SQL, but i have used ParameterDirection.ReturnValue. then not need this, only we have to return a value

Comment: yes, i had missed second argument in SqlDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery() function which is CommandType.StoredProcedure. means we have to write like that:     SqlDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlDataAccess.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "PR_insertUpdateWebAdStatistics", _param);      Thanks now it is working well

Answer (score 0):

use parameter direction as  "*ParameterDirection.ReturnValue*" for "@RetVal". so there is no need to specify this parameter in stored procedure.

And on the retrival of its value use

```
_param[1].value.toString();
```

and then convert it into integet.